# How to integrate jauggernaut with rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins

How to integrate juggernaut plugin with rails 3 and ruby 1.9.3

What are the steps to follow.

I Know about maccman / juggernaut_plugin on github, but I need detail information.

Please advice me.
thanks

Comment: try the `nodejs` one of maccman it more update then the ruby one

Comment: thks for suggestion...but i want to know how to integrate..not what to use.

Comment: I think the `github` [readme](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut) is quite adequate at least I did it  using the instruction in the `readme`  hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at 
http://www.golygon.com/2010/12/private-chat-room-in-ruby-on-rails-3-0 
or 
http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2010/05/juggernaut-rails-chat-part-i-what-is-and-how-to-install. Its with rails-3 and ruby-1.9.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.